# cypress , how to make different it to each row in the result from DB

Tags: mysql, loops, cypress

I am trying to read a mysql query in Cypress, and use each data from row that appear there in a different 'it' section, so it wouldn't fail the rest of the test if one of the rows fail. I guess because Cypress can't execute Cypress commands its make the error 'cypress cant find any tests'. Any solutions?:)

```
describe('FUTURES', ()=>{
it('getFutureByLeagueName',()=>{
    let the_query = 'SELECT * FROM db.dbTable;'
    cy.task('queryDb',the_query ).then((result)=> {
        for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            it('' , ()=> {
                functionsPage.apiTest('/'+result[i].name) 
            })
            
           
        }
    
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of trying to loop through 'it' instances, did you try adding ```{failOnStatusCode: false}```? Maybe this can already get you the desired result.
```functionsPage.apiTest('/'+result[i].name, {failOnStatusCode:false})```

Comment: NOT WORKING :( :(

Comment: is theres a way to use soft assertion?